# How to compare the value of a tagName and a string in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, tagname

I try to find out when the tagname is "MAIN" an then to trigger some functions but unfortunately I steadily receive the error

This condition will always return true since the types "Event" and "Main" have no overlaps.

```
onMouseWheel(evt) {
event = evt.target.tagName;
while(event != 'MAIN')
  event = evt.target.parentNode.tagName;
}
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: this isn't a very angular approach, use the built in mousewheel event directive and attach it to the elements you're interested in

Comment: You should declare the variable: `let event = ...` (and consider using a different name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular approach to this is to attach the angular `(wheel)` directive to the element you're interested in and handle it that way.

```
<main (wheel)="onMouseWheel($event)"></main>
```

This way the wheel event is only triggering the handler when it occurs on elements you're interested in.